# Redirect from all pages with index.php to non index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this rule for redirect from index.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*):443$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it works only for address: site.com/index.php to site.com
I need to redirect from all adress who contain index.php, for example site.com/categories/rings/index.php to site.com/categories/rings/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` rules are the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want to keep the port `RewriteCond`, you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this example does not work.
It not redirect address  site.com/categories/rings/index.php to site.com/categories/rings/

Comment: @Serg Try clearing your cache in your browser before testing.

Comment: It not redirect url site.com/categories/rings/index.php to site.com/categories/rings/
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*):443$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: If url site.com/about/index.php redirect works fine to site.com/about/

Comment: @Serg That's the code from your question. Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I replace my code whit this:
`RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: @Serg That would work. If it doesn’t work when you clear you’re cache, something else is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

⭐ I use this in my .htaccess file in laravel project

```
# Redirect index.php to non index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)/index.(php|html) /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/index.(php|html) / [R=301,L]
```